# Can I use tee for large logoutputs on a server 7/24?

Tags: command-line, tee

The tee command https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35935/how-to-log-to-file-and-to-console writes the console output as well to a file.

However when I open the file while the main program is still running the logfile is empty. This is not a problem as long I've the output once the terminal window of the program is closed.

Is it possible/recommended to use the tee command for large logoutputs (eg. multiple MBs) on a long running command (eg. many weeks)?

Or is there a better alternative to write the console output as well to a file?